# Opening large files in Vim

Tags: vim

Is it possible to make Vim issue a warning prompt when asked to open a large file?

Currently when I try to open log files(whose size I haven't checked) Vim or VM on which Vim is running crashes.

Comment: How big a file are you talking about? Vim shouldn't outright crash even on large files, just get really slow. What version of Vim? There were several fixes applied recently to fix Vim's handling of files exceeding some 32-bit limits, if Vim is compiled for 64-bit support, IIRC.

Comment: Easy: make a conscious effort to check the size.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a function like this one.

```
  :function OpenFile()
  :let size =getfsize(@%)
  :if size>100000    "more than 100kb
  :echo "Warning: This is a large file"
  :endif
  :end function
```

Now, call this function when a file is opened, BufEnter does it for you!

```
   :au BufEnter *.* :call OpenFile()
```

Put all the above lines in ~/.vimrc.

This will throw warning if the file size is greater than 100000.

Comment: If you want the filesize to be evaluated in KB, you can add `/1024` to the number (like 100000). If you want it to be more simplified with KB and MB, we can add one more line for that calculation.

Comment: Bad idea.  `BufEnter` runs _after_ the file has been open.  Worse, it also runs when switching buffers.  I believe the OP wants to have a chance to abort _before_ opening a large file.

Comment: I guess he has written about 'issuing warning prompt'. I will change it now.

Comment: Well, after opening the file the OP gets a crash as a prompt, :) so having a chance to abort seems like the only way to read it that makes some sense.

Comment: Sato is correct, <code>BufEnter</code> runs <em>after</em> the file opens and does not give a chance to abort opening the file.